# tar: Backing up an encrypted /home folder?

Tags: 10.04, permissions, backup, encryption, tar

After some trial and error, I've managed to backup my Ubuntu 10.04 workstation and it's time for my Laptop. It also runs 10.04, but has an encrypted `/home` folder.

Running the below snippet as `root` clearly doesn't work well with encryption, so how should I do this?

```
sudo -i
cd /
tar -cvpzf sysbackup-20110821.tar.gz \
    --exclude=/sysbackup-20110821.tar.gz \
    --exclude=/proc \
    --exclude=/lost+found \
    --exclude=/sys \
    --exclude=/mnt \
    --exclude=/media \
    --exclude=/dev /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ecryptfs man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man7/ecryptfs.7.html), try to mount it somewhere as a regular folder, and then execute your tar command.

```
sudo -i
mkdir /mnt/usermount 2>/dev/null
cd /
mount -t ecryptfs /home/user /mnt/usermount -o passwd=<your_pass_phrase> no_sig_cache
tar -cvpzf sysbackup-20110821.tar.gz \
  --exclude=/sysbackup-20110821.tar.gz \
  --exclude=/proc \
  --exclude=/lost+found \
  --exclude=/sys \
  --exclude=/media \
  --exclude=/dev /
umount /mnt/usermount
rm -rf /mnt/usermount
```

Note above that I removed the `--exclude /mnt` and also created the directory `/mnt/usermount` just in case you don't have it.

Comment: What a `-o` mount option without arguments is supposed to do? I think you messed-up mount command line.

Comment: Again, I suppose no spaces are allowed in `-o` arguments. Generally you find them separated by commas without spaces, like for exampe `-o defaults,noatime,umask=0022`